# Функция для записи данных в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть функция (для вопроса упростил ее очень сильно):

```
var participantsQuarterFinal = [];
var participantsSemiFinal = [];
var filterNextStage = []; (после кое каких действий в нем появляется 3 объекта).

var distribution = function (array) {
 array = filterNextStage.slice(0, 1);
 дальше идут манипуляции с array.
}
```

Я хотел сделать так, чтобы я мог вызывать функцию distribution и передавать ей аргументом название любого массива (как пример participantsQuarterFinal или participantsSemiFinal) и чтобы туда записывались данные:

> array = filterNextStage.slice(0, 1);

Но в итоге при запуске

> distribution(participantsQuarterFinal);

Ничего никуда не записывается. Массив participantsQuarterFinal остается пустым. Я решил проверить и оказалось, что если вместо параметра array сразу написать название массива, то запись происходит. Но мне нужно, чтобы я смог передавать название любого массива. Что делать? Попрошу Вас отвечать мне в довольно понятной форме, так как с JS только начинаю знакомиться. Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var distribution = function (array) {
 array.splice(0, array.length, ...filterNextStage.slice(0, 2));
 //дальше идут манипуляции с array.
}

var a1 = [1,2,3,4];
var filterNextStage = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log("before", JSON.stringify(a1));
distribution(a1);
console.log("after", JSON.stringify(a1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Выяснил, что если передавать в качестве параметра название массива, куда записывать, то работать не будет, так как переменная внутри функции (параметр) это локальная область видимости. Поэтому стоит сделать вот так:

```
var participantsQuarterFinal = [];
var filterNextStage = [{}, {}, {}];

var distribution = function () {
 return filterNextStage.slice(0, 1);
}

participantsQuarterFinal = distribution ();
```

Возможно, очень криво написал вопрос, извиняюсь. Спасибо тем, кто ответил!

Comment: Я же показал Вам, как внутри функции изменить содержимое массива, переданного через параметр.

Comment: Да, спасибо Вам огромное!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Пустой массив
let z = [];


//Функция с двумя агрументами, первый аргумент название массива, второй аргумент то что надо добавить в массив
function pushIn (arr, someting) {
    arr.push(someting);
}


//проверяем
pushIn(z, 'Book');
console.log(z);
```